# VAB Excel Form - Listbox index property given control - type mismatch

Tags: vba, listbox, controls

I'm using code (from here) that loops through controls a form.
When I find a particular listbox control, I want to get the listbox index.
How do I access a listbox property given a generic control?

Comment: I assume "from here" means from SO. Can you link to it, or paste some code in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
Dim lb as MSForms.ListBox
Dim ctrl as MSForms.Control

For each ctrl in UserForm.Controls
   If TypeName(ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
       Set lb = ctrl

       'Voila! Now you have a variable "lb" which represents the generic listbox control

       MsgBox lb.Name & " listIndex = " & lb.ListIndex 'etc.

   End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks David. I had almost that. Was missing the "MSForms." prefix. I had guessed this should be assumed from within Excel but including it stopped my "Type mismatch" error.

Comment: If you're unsure of what type of variable, you can always just `Dim lb As Variant` or `As Object` although these will not give you the intellisense assistance that a strongly typed variable would, the code should work either way.